# How to distinguish tables from views using Metadata in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: database, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to describe my database content. I am using Metadata object, reflect method and looping over tables. (Code below)
When I am looping over the tables I need to distinguish which one of them is a table and which one is a view. I can't seem to find any attributes or method that could help me.

```py
metadata = MetaData(bind=self.engine, schema=schema)

metadata.reflect(views=True)

for key, table in metadata.tables.items():
    print(table.name)
    # Here I need to know if table is a table or a view
```

I tried printing the type of the table object, but it's always type `sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* that SQLAlchemy distinguishes between tables and views - both are `Table` instances. A workaround - at the cost of an extra query - might be to compare the results of reflecting with and without views:

```py
tmeta = metadata.reflect(engine)
vmeta = metadata.reflect(engine, views=True)

view_names = vmeta.tables.keys() - t.meta.tables.keys()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer snakecharmerb! I also thought of this solution but I was wondering if there is an attribute that could tell me this without running another query 

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've defined a view as:

```py
class MyView(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_view"
    __table_args__ = {"info": {"is_view": True}}
```

You can discriminate a view with the following:

```py
    for table_object in db.Model.metadata.tables.values():
        print(table_object.info.get("is_view", False))
```

Comment: You need to loop over `db.Model.metadata.tables.values() ` for this code to work  - as it is, `table_ojbect` is a string.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include the `.values()` method - thanks!